# searching and listing WPF resource dictionaries in a folder

Tags: wpf, search, list, resourcedictionary

I'm making a WPF application that is going to have multiple skins branded in by our build system.  Ideally we would like the application to list off the skins available as some builds will have one to many skins.

At runtime is there a way to enumerate all the Resource Dictionaries in a specific folder?

I want to avoid hard coding the XAML filenames in my codebehind as this is a changing situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of.

You can enumerate all BAML (compiled XAML) files as follows:

```
  var resourcesName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g";
  var manager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(resourcesName, assembly);
  var resourceSet = manager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
  var allXamlFiles =
    from entry in resourceSet.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
    let fileName = (string)entry.Key
    where fileName.EndsWith(".baml")
    select fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length-5) + ".xaml";
```

There is no way to know which ones of these are ResourceDictionaries and which are other XAML such as Windows or UserControls without actually loading them.  So the answer to your direct question is "no" unless you load each XAML you find to check if it is a ResourceDictionary.  This would be very slow.

On the other hand, if you're willing to use a naming scheme for your ResourceDictionaries, then you can enumerate all BAMLs in your assembly and select whichever match your naming scheme, and trust that they are ResourceDictionaries.  Just extend the "where" clause in the above query.

Therefore the answer is "sort of."

Comment: I can understand the concept of what you're getting at, but it's not building for me. I'm assuming "assembly" is from Assemgly.GetExecutingAssembly(). Also the constructor for manager is probably ResourceManager(resourcesName, assembly). However I think the LINQ query isn't right since resourceSet doesn't have an OfType<>() function

Comment: I copied this from my own working application code, but as I was pasting the code I did some last-minute refactoring and messed up the ResourceManager constructor. I have fixed my answer to correct the bug.

Comment: As for the other error, I think you merely forgot to `using System.Linq;` since the `OfType<>()` extension method is declared there.

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution i found @ microsoft

WPF wraps the `ResourceDictionary` in the "Assembly.g.resources", we can get the resource name "Assembly.g.resources" by `GetManifestResourceNames()`. After that we can use `ResourceReader` class to read the Resource from the `ResourceStream`.

```
 foreach (string str in Application.ResourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()){
txt.Text += str + "\n";
 {
  Stream st = Application.ResourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(str);
  using (ResourceReader resourceReader = new ResourceReader(st))
  {
   foreach (DictionaryEntry resourceEntry in resourceReader)
   {
    txt.Text +="\t: "+ resourceEntry.Key + "\n";
   }
  }
 }
}
```

second answer

You can use `Assembly.Load()` to load the external assembly and read the resource  dictionaries from it.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Assembly Name String"); 
foreach (string str in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
 {
  Stream st = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(str);
  using (ResourceReader resourceReader = new ResourceReader(st))
  {
   foreach (DictionaryEntry resourceEntry in resourceReader)
   {
    .....
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add ResourceDictionary at runtime.

```
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(...)
```

Comment: I don't know the names of the skin so I need to list them first before adding them.