# How to get all the image resources in a project’s sub folders?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources, embedded-resource

[image]

I have a project like this; I want to get all the images in the “Images” folder.

If all the png files are stored in a folder on the disk, this would be easy.

But they are embedded in the project, then how can I access them?

Or even further, how do I get a tree data structure of the image resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access them using a package URI:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(“pack://application:,,,/Images/ImageCategory1/Burn Disc.png”));
```

If you want to get the folder structure:

I am afraid there is no folder structure other than that the structure in the project is added to the name of each resource.

Fortunately there is a way to enumerate all resources: [searching and listing WPF resource dictionaries in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765920/searching-and-listing-wpf-resource-dictionaries-in-a-folder)