# Get all Resources in a Java source folder

Tags: java, bufferedimage, embedded-resource, offline

The following code grants me access to a specific PNG resource within my project:

```
BufferedImage temp = ImageIO.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("play.png"));
```

However, I have *n* images that I don't have to have to hardcode ("play.png", "pause.png", etc); without having an external image library (which I would simply loop through with `File`), is there a way to get all images within the project?

Ideally, all files within a specific source folder, really. Or source folders. `getResources` only seems to work for multiples of a specific named resource, which isn't what I want.

**EDIT**:

To be clear, this is a local project / application; it isn't intended to be a servlet or otherwise deployed on the Web. Question updated with the `offline` tag in case this is applicable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the image resources in a project’s sub folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996847/how-to-get-all-the-image-resources-in-a-project-s-sub-folders)

Comment: I did already check that answer, but that's in C# and this question is clearly in Java . .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193786/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-correctly

Comment: Folders are a GUI concept, where you seem to mean directories.  But application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.  Further to that, embedded resources are not open to being 'listed' in the way you seem to want.  As an alternative, prepare a list as the Jars are being built, include the list in the Jar.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - yeah, it does seem that way. Looks like the best alternative is to create an array (or similar) with matching names for all resources and iterate over that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.Here I am trying to get all the images in a folder named `images` in a servlet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
     HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String pathToImages = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images");
     File[] files = new File(pathToImages).listFiles();
     showImages(files);
 }
 public static void showImages(File[] files) {
        for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can see how that would work for you, but I'm dubious that `getServletContext()` would work within a local / offline application. Will test and get back to you.

Comment: if its a normal java project,you can  try `String pathToImages ="src/images";` assuming images folder is under src.

Comment: There is a difference in how Java handles embedded resources that prevents this from working once deployed, but thanks regardless :)