# How to find and remove all unused resources in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

Is there a way to find all unused resources (those that have x:Key attribute set)? By resources I mean the WPF/XAML objects created in ResourceDictionary. This is WPF/XAML specific question, not related to .resx files or other kind of resources such as images or binary files.

I have been working on a project for a while and was testing some different styles for same controls but during the time everything got mixed up so I'd like to remove all resources not used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a file search (using [Find in Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dechx2tz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) across your solution for each of your named resources. Not very elegant, but it will do the job.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765920/searching-and-listing-wpf-resource-dictionaries-in-a-folder) question for some assistance in finding all of the resources in your application.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found any other way than this either.