# Any way to get a list of templates in a folder programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I know I can do

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/Templates/MyTemplate.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
```

to get a specific template from the project at runtime, but how do I list what templates are available in that folder? Ideally I'd like to have the startup process just add anything in that folder without having to specifically reference them in App.xaml and risk merge conflicts every time somebody changes it.

GetManifestResourceNames seems to return something totally different.

I'm tempted to create a pre-build process that generates a resource dictionary that enumerates everything in that folder, but that seems hacky and messy.

Comment: What _does_ `GetManifestResourceNames()` return? Also, AFAIK, folders aren't really a concept, it's strings all the way down, you'll have to manually parse the names and check whether they begin with the folder string you want.

Comment: It returns a single resource that isn't what I'm looking for, AFAIK.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765920/searching-and-listing-wpf-resource-dictionaries-in-a-folder

Comment: @KlausGütter: Perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can xamlreader.load to read all xaml files into resource dictionary objects and merge them into application.current.resources. Which is where your app xaml merges into.

No referencing in app.xaml.

```
        string folder = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xaml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f);
            ResourceDictionary rd = XamlReader.Load(sr.BaseStream) as ResourceDictionary;
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
        }
```

I've not been terribly careful with the choice of currentdirectory and of course you may want to put your resource dictionaries somewhere else.

This approach errors if you have x:Shared on anything in a resource dictionary. It tells you that resource dictionary must be compiled. Academic if you don't use that though.

In the unlikely event you have some other .xaml files sat there next to your exe, you could add "rd" on your resource dictionary name. Or make them .txt files perhaps.

Comment: That's only going to work if the xaml files are copied to the output directory, but they're not.

Comment: You wrote " Ideally I'd like to have the startup process just add anything in that folder". Substitute whatever "that folder" is for the output directory.

Comment: I meant a folder in the project- that doesn't equate to a folder in the output directory.

Comment: Make it equate to a folder in the output directory. Make these txt files and set their properties to content and copy to output directory if newer. Or download using a service. If these are folder in your project why aren't you simply merging them in app.xaml anyway?